# loading data to a table containing clob datatype, from a flat file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to populate a table with the values taken from a flat file using SQLLDR.The problem is that one of the fields in the table is of CLOB datatype(lets say the field name is COMMENTS). In the control file, i have mentioned the datatype for this field as CHAR(4000), since the usage of CLOB in control file was not working. But  this also fails when there is a EndOfLine present in the field. Thus it tries to load the next line as new record and fails.

Please suggest a solution to this....
Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of the database?  which OS platform?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do this programatically using perl or something similar.  Alternatively, you can use something like the example given here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/LoadLobDataUsingSqlLoader.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why the CLOB specification in the control file failed, but if you're at 9i or later, you *should* be able to [load a CLOB via sqlldr](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch07.htm#1006805).

Failing that, you might be able to work out [assembling logical records from physical records](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1005518) via CONTINUEIF.